# Alternative way to "preload" attribute

Tags: javascript, html4

Hi everyone and sorry for my bad english. I'm writing code for an exam at my university.The exam it's about coding with HTML4 and JavaScript. The point is : i have a set of sounds to play when some events occours but the machines where my project will be examinated are SO old. I thought to preload  all the tracks before launching all the javascript code so that when i'll have to play multiple sounds or more istances of the same sound i'll get no lag. My problem is that we have to use HTML 4. I know that in HTML 5 there is the "preload" attribute that can be insert in the audio tag, but even with an hour of research on the internet i didn't find nothing. Could someone give me and advice, trick or a link to solve my problem?

My solution was : the little game starts with a menu and if the player clicks start the audio load starts ( here is the problem because when i create the object nodes with the dom all the audios auto-play ) and than the game starts. I'd like to only load the audio without the collateral auto-play because i have already scripted the function that plays the audio when needed ( or if you have a better solution i can rewrite my code listening to your advice ). If you want some parts of my code just tell me to post them and i'll edit this question.

For now i'll post just this ( it's the part where i load the sound )

```
function create_audio_set()
{
   var new_element_node = null                                                                   ;
   var body             = document.getElementById( "game_body" ) ;

       // Olaf death sounds
       for ( var i = 1 ; i <= 4 ; i++ )
     {
         var new_element_node = document.createElement ( "object" )                                      ;
         new_element_node.setAttribute ( "data", "Media/audio/Sample_dead_olaf_" + i + ".wav" )                ;
         new_element_node.setAttribute ( "id",   "Sample_dead_olaf_" + i )                                                         ;
         new_element_node.style.visibility = "hidden"                                                                                                  ;
         body.appendChild ( new_element_node )                                                                                                                 ;
         set_element_style ( "Sample_dead_olaf_" + i, "absolute", 1, 1, 1, 1, -5 )                                             
     }

     ....
     ....

}
```

set_element_style it's a function that sets the style catching the element with the "id" attribute, setting the positioning, left, top, height, width and zindex ;

KEEP IN MIND THAT I CANNOT USE DEPRECATED ELEMENTS OR ATTRIBUTES.

Thanks everybody!